# Unexpected behavior for static init in LINQPad

Tags: c#, linqpad

I run the following LINQPad's C# Program twice:

```
void Main()
{
    new Bar();
}

class Bar
{
    static DateTime staticInitTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime initTime = DateTime.Now;

    public Bar()
    {
        staticInitTime.Dump("staticInitTime");
        initTime.Dump("initTime");
    }
}
```

and while I see no problems with the results of the first run:

```
staticInitTime
3/4/2017 11:45:28 PM 

initTime
3/4/2017 11:45:28 PM
```

I can't understanding the results of the second run, just a few seconds after the first:

```
staticInitTime
3/4/2017 11:45:28 PM 

initTime
3/4/2017 11:45:40 PM
```

Specifically: why staticInitTime keeps it's value between the runs?
Only when I re-build the code, the value of staticInitTime gets initialized, but then only for the first run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Linqpad is smart. By default, it doesn't build a new AppDomain each time you run your query. So any static initialization will be preserved until you rebuild. You can change this behavior in the advanced preferences:

[image]

By the way, totally off topic: Linqpad rocks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And yes, it's an amazing tool!

Comment: You can also use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F5` to manually unload the previous query process but it would be nice to have a pragma or `Util` setting to adjust this - I have a `static` class in My Extensions and when I use it, I have to remember to unload or manually call an Init for it.